# Passing in column names to a function that runs another function in R

Tags: r

I am using the dplyr package to run an eggregation across a dataframe. For example I can pass my data frame in along with the 2 columns I want to aggregate by (Col_1, Col_2) and the column that actually gets aggregated (Col_to_Agg).

```
agg_frame <- dcast(setDT(data_frame), Col_1+Col_2~Col_to_Agg, length)
```

If I have this method inside a custom function, how can I pass in Col_1, Col2 and Col_to_Agg? It doesn't work if I just pass in those columns as names.

In other words I want to do this:

```
aggregate <- function(data_frame, Col_1, Col_2, Col_to_Agg) {

    agg_frame <- dcast(setDT(data_frame), Col_1+Col_2~Col_to_Agg, length)
    return(agg_frame)

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`as.formula(paste(Col_1,'+',Col_2,'~',Col_to_Agg))`

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you sir.